# Bash: How to download data from Google Form

Tags: bash, download, url

**How can I download the `.csv` of the responses of a `Google Form` from Bash?**

I tried

```
wget https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gRMnKkqKaDAhpm6ytfvZEYfD9_j9HzDk1Q4HgMYC7Xg/edit#gid=1933231618
```

but it downloads the HTML/CSS code for the page and not the `.csv` file and it makes sense. Here is what the window looks like for info

[image]

In order to download the `.csv` one must click on `file>Download as>csv`. I fail to know what the URL (if any exists) corresponds to the `.csv` document.

Comment: You need to use [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk), not just wget your document page you see in the browser.  Depending on which API you are using (e.g. this is with an oauth token):  `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <my token>' "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=<doc_id>&exportFormat=csv"`  Alternatively, you could write a script with selenium to log in and click the necessary buttons.

Comment: Can you let me know a little more about what `<mytoken>` is and what the `<doc_id>` is? Is `<mytoken>` my Google email address? Is `<doc_id>` the long sequence `/d/` and `/edit#` in the URL I wrote in the post?

Comment: You need to visit the link provided and register for a "developer key". The document id is probably the `/d/` portion, but you'll need to read their docs. We don't generally write the scripts for askers on SU.

Comment: [Download unpublished Google spreadsheet as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10860134/13697228)